# How to make text show up after a checkbox with JS and without modifying HTML manually?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I am having trouble ... How do I create a new node and insert it AFTER the checkbox that is titled "Special Order"?

But it replaces my checkbox with the text.  Also I cannot change HTML as it is created for me by a 3rd party library.  Any changes to HTML are to be done via i.e. JS/jQuery.

Also, for some reason my particular HTML is not always showing the text, when it should be.  I can edit text with Firefox Developer Tools but it doesn't show after the checkbox which is weird... I am probably doing something wrong.

I tried doing

```js
var textnode = document.createTextNode("TEST"); 
$( "input[name='submittal[special_order]']" ).parent().html(textnode);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="submittal_form_info">


  <label><span>XXX:</span>
  <input name="submittal[xxx]" value="0" type="hidden">
  <input name="submittal[xxx]" value="1" type="checkbox">
  </label>


  <label><span>Special Order:</span>
  <input name="submittal[special_order]" value="0" type="hidden">
  <input name="submittal[special_order]" title="Is this a special order?" value="1" type="checkbox">
  </label>

</fieldset>
```

What I am trying to do is to add text of my choosing after the square checkbox icon in my HTML.

Comment: `html()` replaces all contents... try `append()`

Comment: hah!  hey that seems to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can target the `:last` input and use `after()`

```js
var textnode = document.createTextNode("TEST"); 
$( "input[name='submittal[special_order]']:last" ).after(textnode);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="submittal_form_info">


  <label><span>XXX:</span>
  <input name="submittal[xxx]" value="0" type="hidden">
  <input name="submittal[xxx]" value="1" type="checkbox">
  </label>


  <label><span>Special Order:</span>
  <input name="submittal[special_order]" value="0" type="hidden">
  <input name="submittal[special_order]" title="Is this a special order?" value="1" type="checkbox">
  </label>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `.append()` it to the html instead of using `.html()` as that replaces the html.

```js
var textnode = document.createTextNode("TEST"); 
$( "input[name='submittal[special_order]']" ).parent().append(textnode);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="submittal_form_info">


  <label><span>XXX:</span>
  <input name="submittal[xxx]" value="0" type="hidden">
  <input name="submittal[xxx]" value="1" type="checkbox">
  </label>


  <label><span>Special Order:</span>
  <input name="submittal[special_order]" value="0" type="hidden">
  <input name="submittal[special_order]" title="Is this a special order?" value="1" type="checkbox">
  </label>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you wanna do exactly, but this script will go to each input type=checkbox with a title attribute, and append the text in title="" next to it

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"][title]').each(
    function(i, input) {
        $(input).after($(input).attr('title'))
    }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset id="submittal_form_info">


  <label><span>XXX:</span>
  <input name="submittal[xxx]" value="0" type="hidden">
  <input name="submittal[xxx]" value="1" type="checkbox">
  </label>


  <label><span>Special Order:</span>
  <input name="submittal[special_order]" value="0" type="hidden">
  <input name="submittal[special_order]" title="Is this a special order?" value="1" type="checkbox">
  </label>

</fieldset>
```